# Border who change of height between resolution

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, border

I create dynamically a border with a function who is :

```
func getBorderLabel(width : CGFloat) -> UIView{
    let borderView = UIView(frame : CGRect(x : 0, y : 0, width : width, height : 2))

    let topColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x09D2E3)
    let bottomColor = UIColor(rgb : 0xF600FF)

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [topColor.cgColor,
                            bottomColor.cgColor]

    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.3)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.8)
    gradientLayer.frame = borderView.bounds
    gradientLayer.masksToBounds = false
    gradientLayer.opacity = 1

    borderView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

    return borderView
}
```

everything work well but when I run the code in the simulator I have different border height like show the screen (**IPHONE X**):

[image]

The second one has a smaller size than the first... but the code is the same and the height is fixed at 2px...

My function `getBorderLabel` is called in a `textFieldClass` builder like this :

```
let borderView = getBorderLabel(width: TFView.bounds.width)
let containerBorderView = UIView(frame : CGRect(x : 0,
                                                y : TFView.bounds.height * 0.40 + 22,
                                                width : borderView.bounds.width,
                                                height : borderView.bounds.height))
containerBorderView.addSubview(borderView)

TFView.addSubview(containerBorderView)
```

absolutely nothing breaks some part of the border

Please, where I go wrong ?

Comment: And how you are calling `getBorderLabel`?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I edit my question

Comment: Simulator is unreliable, check on another device on the simulator. (Different screen size)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I add a new screen from an iphone 8 (simulator) to my question, the problem disappear..  So, the problem comes from the simulator ?

Comment: @El-Burritos yes that can happen with simulator. But you need to check with real device.

Comment: Yes, you can verify it by resizing your simulator screen too.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri When I resize the simulator, the height of the borders change again .... So I will test later on real device. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Because the pixels on the simulator are the pixels on your screen, so they do not accurately reflect points. It should work fine on a real device.

Comment: Can I Know why the downvote 3 month after without explanation?